# c# class to csv without internal object reference and without modify original class

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, csv

For backup reason i need to write a job that get all the record in a database older thena  certain data, save to csv and send to remote storage and then delete the record from database

So for each class i create a indentical class with all the information for write on csv (see example below) and without object reference and everything works fine. The problem is: when i modify the main class i need to remeber to update the model class.

There is a way to avoid this?

Edit:
My question is: there is a way to specify FieldQuoted, DelimitedRecord and to also specify which field ignore in FileHelper?

Example

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace backend.DataModel
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class Attachment
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public int AttachmentTypeCode { get; set; }
        public string AttachmentContent;
        public System.DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        public string Md5 { get; set; }
        public virtual AttachmentType AttachmentType1 { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace BackupDatabase.Model
{
    [DelimitedRecord(";")]
    [IgnoreEmptyLines()]
    public class AttachmentBackupModel
    {
        [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted)]
        public string Id;
        public int AttachmentTypeCode;
        [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted)]
        public string ReferenceId;
        [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted)]
        public string AttachmentContent;
        [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff")]
        public DateTime CreationDate;
        [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted)]
        public string Md5;
        public AttachmentBackupModel() { }

        public AttachmentBackupModel(Attachment attachment)
        {
            Id = attachment.Id;
            AttachmentType = attachment.AttachmentType;
            AttachmentContent = attachment.AttachmentContent;
            Md5 = attachment.Md5;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does it have to be a fixed format or is generating a csv from model definition in EF ok?

Comment: It's generate a csv from model. So if the model change (eg: add a column) the csv need to be updated with the new column

Comment: Since the two models are decoupled (`Attachment` and `AttachmentBackupModel`) I think you the only way is to maintain them manually.

Comment: That's my question. There is a way to specify the FieldQuoted on the filehelper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a generic solution using DelimitedClassBuilder to build the Record definition from Entity frameworks model data.

```
public void Export<T>(DbContext ctx, IEnumerable<T> data)
{
    ObjectContext octx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext;
    EntityType storageEntityType = octx.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.SSpace).OfType<EntityType>().First(es => es.Name == typeof(T).Name);

    var cb = new DelimitedClassBuilder(typeof(T).Name, ";") { IgnoreEmptyLines = true };
    foreach (var prop in storageEntityType.Properties)
    {
        if (!prop.IsComplexType ...)
        {
            var fieldBuilder = cb.AddField(prop.Name, prop.TypeName);
            if (fieldBuilder.FieldType == "System.String")
            {
                cb.LastField.TrimMode = TrimMode.Both;
                cb.LastField.QuoteMode = QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted;
            }
            ...
        }
    }

    var engine = new FileHelperEngine(cb.CreateRecordClass());

    ...
}
```